# Orbot disconnects randomly

Tags: orbot, android

I am using Orbot 15.1.2 on an Android 5.0.2 LRX22G device. Orbot shuts down for no reason, when I go to the big button then it starts connecting again. I have checked the allow background starts option, and the no network auto-sleep is off. Any idea what could be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Having the same problem.
Android 6 on wikio sunny though.

Comment: In my case, my phone was running out of memory and Android was shutting down Orbot to free up memory. I have since traded for a better phone.